# Using IONIC Storage Service, how to get and return stored JSON data?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I’m new to Ionic.

I'm able to store A JSON object (data) using IONIC Storage Service; however, when I try to retrieve the JSON data, I get undefined.

I appreciate any help on this - below is my code:

Provider: storage-service.ts:
I’m able to store and output data, but I cannot return the data:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

constructor(public storage: Storage){}

public storeData (data) {
    this.storage.set('data', data);
}

public getStoredData() {
         this.storage.get('data').then((val) => {
        console.dir(val);  //****** this outputs the object.
        return val;  //***** this returns undefined
        });
  }
 }
```

my-page.ts:

```
import {StorageService} from "../../providers/storage-service";

constructor(public storageService: StorageService) {

    //***** this outputs undefined, what I'm doing wrong?
    console.dir(this.storageService.getStoredData());
}
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Ionic storage is based on promises, you need to return that promise in the service:

```
public getStoredData() {
  return this.storage.get('data').then((val) => { // <-- Here!
    console.dir(val);
    return val;
  });
}
```

And also use `then` to get the value in your page

```
import { StorageService } from "../../providers/storage-service";

constructor(public storageService: StorageService) {

  this.storageService.getStoredData().then(data => {
    console.dir(data); // <-- Like this!
  });

}
```

**[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)** you can find some more information about how to use promises.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but my code looks messy. Is there a better way to do this: `constructor(public storageService: StorageService) {

       this.storageService.getStoredData()
            .then(data => {
                let hash = data.hash;
                let params = {'user_hash': user_hash};
                this.eventService.getEvents(headers, params)
                    .subscribe((data: any) => {
                            this.events = data;
                        },
                        (error: any) => {
                        });

            });
    }
}
`

Comment: I think your code looks good. It's hard to know without some more context to be honest.

Comment: Storageservice.ts  `loadData(key:string) {
  return this.storage.get(key).then((val) => { 
    return val;
  });
}` home.ts `this.interservice.loadData('auth').then((res) => {
          this.activeuser = res;
        });
        console.log("Home",this.activeuser)` console return undefined. what's my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return

```
public getStoredData() {
  return this.storage.get('data').then((val) => {
           return val;  
   });
  }
 }
```